# Evaluating inverse Discrete Time Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Say I have some discrete elements $b_{k}$ with $k=0,1,...,N-1$. I know that each element is given by a series of the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
b_{k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}e^{-i2\pi kj/N}.\frac{1}{1-e^{-i2\pi j/N \pm ic}}
\end{eqnarray}
where $c\in \mathbb{R}$, and therefore $|e^{\pm ic}|= 1$. By going to the $N\to \infty$ limit, we can write:
\begin{eqnarray}
b_{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}dx e^{-ikx}.\frac{1}{1-ae^{-ix}} && |a|\leq 1
\end{eqnarray}
According to the Wikipedia page on DTFT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform), the following holds:
\begin{eqnarray}
x[n]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}dx e^{+inx}.\frac{1}{1-ae^{-ix}} = a^{n}u[n]
\end{eqnarray}
However, in my example above, we always have $k\geq 0$, and if we use this I obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
b_{k}=a^{-k}u[-k]
\end{eqnarray}
How does this match with the original definition of the $b_{k}$ terms? I am a bit confused with the fact that $u[-k]$ is only distinct from zero for $k\leq 0$, however this contradicts the original definition given above with $k\geq 0$. Is the DTFT formula above not correct in this case? Or how could one make this consistent?

Comment: You have basically sampled the DTFT of an infinite-length sequence with a period $1/N$ and have taken a finite number of samples ($N$) (effectively, you have first multiplied the DTFT with the rectangular window). Applying IDFT to these samples will give you the superposition of aliased versions of the distorted (due to rectangular window) sequence in $k \in \{0, \ldots, N-1\}$.